# Why every time i run my flutter app on Windows this exception happen?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-windows

Every time I run my Flutter app this message thrown:

I reviewed everything but I don't know why happened. This happens every time I run my Flutter app:

[image]

This is flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.630], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.7.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.81.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources
• No issues found!
```